# is it possible to upload a file to S3 from a URL in parts? file.aa, file.ab, file.ac

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-requests, boto3

i would like to upload a really large file 3TB from a URL to s3 directly, but want to upload it in parts, similar to if i would split the file on my machine and upload the parts to s3.

I have the following script to upload the file (whole) from url to S3, how can i modify it to upload it to (parts) file.aa, file.ab, file.ac etc..

```
import requests
import boto3

url = "https://example.com/file.tar"
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

session = boto3.Session()
s3 = session.resource('s3')

bucket_name = 'bucket-name'
key = 'file.tar' # key is the name of file on your bucket

bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
bucket.upload_fileobj(r.raw, key)
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading this:

https://medium.com/@niyazi_erd/aws-s3-multipart-upload-with-python-and-boto3-9d2a0ef9b085

Comment: Please expand your answer by at least giving a summary for future readers, in case the linked page disappears in future.

Comment: multipart upload will result in a single file on s3 as the final product, i want my file broken up on S3 when stored so my users can download parts at a time instead of the whole file which is prone to failure since it take a long time to download

Answer (score 0):

A `requests.Response` object, besides a file-like object at `.raw`, also provides an iterator over the content at `.iter_content()`. If you have enough available memory to fit your desired chunk size, You could do something like the following:

```py
import requests
import boto3

url = "https://example.com/file.tar"
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

session = boto3.Session()
s3 = session.resource('s3')

bucket_name = 'bucket-name'
key = 'file.tar' # key is the name of file on your bucket

bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

for i, chunk in enumerate(r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*1024*1024)):  # This would split the file into 1GiB chunks
    bucket.put_object(Body=chunk, Key=f"{key}.{i}")
```

Of course, you could tweak the logic to change how the filename suffix is generated, etc., and there may be better ways to optimize the process, or e.g. use multipart uploads to split into larger chunks than you can afford to hold in memory, but as a quick, minimal modification to your given script that should do the trick.